# invalid extension element: "mime:part" when parsing wsdl

Tags: wsdl, wsimport

I have a problem with importing (generating client code from wsdl) of wsdl file:
idea$ wsimport http://cvx64.daxtra.com/cvvalid/CVXtractorService.wsdl
parsing WSDL...

[ERROR] invalid extension element: "mime:part" (in namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/")

```
Failed to parse the WSDL.
```

idea$ wsimport -version
wsimport version "2.2.9"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Apache CXF wsdl2java helped me.